# nhibernate c# Не создается связь один ко многим nhibernate

Tags: c#, база-данных, nhibernate

Есть таблицы :

```
public class RefPermission : BaseReference {
        public virtual PermissionEnum Permission { get; set; }        
        public virtual RefGroupPermission GroupPermission { get; set; }        
    }
```

и

```
public class RefGroupPermission : BaseReference {
        public virtual ISet<RefPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
        public virtual PermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }                
        public RefGroupPermission()
        {
            this.Permissions = new HashSet<RefPermission>();
        }
    }
```

и я их оверайжу:

```
public class RefPermissionOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<RefPermission> {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<RefPermission> mapping) {            
            mapping.References(x => x.GroupPermission,"grouppermissionid").ForeignKey("grouppermissionid");
        }
    }
```

и

```
public class RefGroupPermissionOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<RefGroupPermission> {        
        public void Override(AutoMapping<RefGroupPermission> mapping) {
            mapping.HasMany(x => x.Permissions);
        }
    }
```

но nhibernate создает новый столбец и думает что это внешний ключ:
[image: картинка]

Как мне сделать внешний ключ по 
свойству GroupPermission в классе RefPermission?

Answer (score 0):

я решил проблдему  нужно добавить в главную таблицу KeyColumns.Add("grouppermissionid"),  вот так:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<RefGroupPermission> mapping) {
            mapping.HasMany(x => x.Permissions).KeyColumns.Add("grouppermissionid");           
        }
```